# VS access breakpoint list when debugging data-driven code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I have a C# program that operates by reading steps from a text file (ie data-driven)  I would really like to be able to debug my way through the text file as if it were just another code file.

In the VS debugger I can click the gutter to set a breakpoint in the text file, but there is no apparent way for the debugger, or my code, to know that this breakpoint has been reached.

Can anyone think of a way to do either of the following?

- Access the debuggers breakpoint list from inside the code being debugged and then tell the debugger "I have just hit breakpoint x"

or

- Tell the debugger "I am about to process line 25 of file fred.txt, so break if you like."

Comment: [Writing a custom debug engine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb145934.aspx)

Comment: Imagine my c# code is an interpreter of another language... the other language is in a text file and I would like to be able to set breakpoints in the other language much the same way as I do in my C# code.

Comment: I guess I would ask why you would need this and how badly? For example, can you accomplish it with data breakpoints in the standard C# debugger instead?

Comment: Thanks for your interest... It would be nice but hardly a deal breaker not to have it.  

The answer to "data breakpoints" is  ... "would you put a data-breakpoint in the code of the C# compiler to break whenever it compiles  the 35th line of a file called fred.cs?" ... no you put the breakpoint in fred.cs.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to harness the power of VS IDE and debugger instead of writing my own :)

Comment: As you can see from the above link, that is not going to be easy. Regarding your point about putting a breakpoint in a compiler, no, but it sounds like you don't have a compiler, you have an interpreter, and I have worked with interpreters in this way before. If it really should be a compiler, have you considered turning it into a transpiler instead (translate your text file into C# code and compile and debug that)? See, for example, T4 text templates, which are debuggable in this exact way. By emitting `#line` directives, you can make bits of code correspond to the original text file.

Comment: You're right of course, it is an interpreter of sorts. Technically I could easily transpile this to c# although that would defeat some of the reasons why this isnt in C# in the first place. Having said that, I'm thinking I could maybe deviously use the #line directive to report script errors by building a class in memory with just #error and #line and compiling that